# Proving inner product generated by matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

For a matrix A, how would I go about proving that the inner product defined by $$\langle\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\rangle=A\mathbf{u}\cdot A\mathbf{v}$$ is indeed an inner product? My math teacher assigned this as a problem, but we haven't talked about inner products yet and reading through my book is not that helpful. If anyone could help me understand the concept better, I would appreciate it!

Comment: Start with the attributes of an inner product.  Then, test to see if $(Au)(Av)$ qualifies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to prove the three properties for vectors $\pmb{u},\pmb{v} \in V$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

1. **Symmetry:** $\newcommand{\inp}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}$
   $\inp{\pmb{u}, \pmb{v}} = \inp{\pmb{v}, \pmb{u}}$ for real valued vectors.
2. **Linearity:** $\inp{\alpha \pmb{u}, \pmb{v}} = \alpha \inp{\pmb{u}, \pmb{v}}$ for real valued vectors.
3. **Positive-definite:** $\inp{\pmb{u}, \pmb{u}} \ge 0$ with equality if and only if $\pmb{u} = 0$, the zero function.

Let's show the three properties:

1. $\newcommand{\inp}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}$
   $\inp{\pmb{u}, \pmb{v}} = \pmb{u}^T A^T A \pmb{v} = (\pmb{u}^T A^T A \pmb{v})^T = \pmb{v}^T A^T A \pmb{u} = \inp{\pmb{v}, \pmb{u}} $.
2. $\inp{\alpha \pmb{u}, \pmb{v}} = (\alpha\pmb{u}^T A^T) A \pmb{v}  = \alpha\pmb{u}^T A^T A \pmb{v}  = \alpha \inp{ \pmb{u}, \pmb{v}}$
3. $\inp{\pmb{u}, \pmb{u}}  = \pmb{u}^T A^T A \pmb{u} \geq 0$ and is $0$ only when $\pmb{u}=\pmb{0}$ or when $\pmb{A}$ is not full column rank (therefore $A^TA$ is positive semi-definite) and $\pmb{u}$ belongs to the column space of $A$. I think you should add this condition.

Answer (score 1):

An inner product is a mapping which assigns a real number to any pair of "vectors", $u$ and $v$ say, and the mapping also has to satisfy some axioms (specific properties). Technically if $V$ is your set of vectors and $\theta$ is an inner product map then $\theta : V\times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Historically people tend to write $<u,v>$ for $\theta ((u,v))$. It is possible to define many different inner products for a particular set of vectors $V$. What the inner product map "does" is give a particular way of assigning "how close two vectors are to each other". More generally it imposes a certain "geometry" on $V$.